# python csv reader skipping 2 rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Trying to read and parse multiple csv files into txt files. Able to read csv and write modified content into txt file. However, while examining the output with original csv, discovered that the first record is NOT writing to text file.

Sample of input csv file

```
INDEX,STRING1,STRING2,NUMBER1,NUMER2,DATE
ABC,abc,bcd,123,321,01-FEB-2017
BCD,bcd,cde,231,432,01-FEB-2017
```

my code:

```
file_list =[]
list_of_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) 
for each_file in list_of_files: #reading csv files from the folder# 
    if (each_file.startswith('report') and each_file.endswith('.csv')): 
        file_list.append(each_file)
        print(each_file) #all ok here#

for f in file_list: #reading from list of files above#
    with open (f, 'r') as fin:
        reader=csv.reader(fin)
        next(reader, None)
        for row in csv.reader(fin):
            #reading date and creating txt file for that date#
            file_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[5],'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
            text_file = open("Report_for_"+file_date+".txt", "w")
            #writing header for the output file#
            text_file.write("<field0>,<date>,<field2>,<field3>,..."+"\n")

            for row in csv.reader(fin):
                if row[1] == 'abc' or row[1] == 'xyz':
                    ASCII=row[0]+','+file_date+','+row[2]+','+row[3]+','+row[4]+','+row[1]
                    text_file.write(ASCII +"\n")
            print ("Processing for " +file_date)
    text_file.close()
print("done....")
```

I used `next(reader, None)` to skip the header. But my code is also skipping first record from all csv files. Even after repeated trial and error not able to figure our where I am going wrong.

Comment: `if row[1] == 'abc' or row[1] == 'xyz'` could become `if row[1] in ('abc', 'xyz')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create **multiple** readers:

```
reader=csv.reader(fin)
next(reader, None)
for row in csv.reader(fin):
    # ...
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
```

Reader objects use buffering, whenever you ask for a row and the buffer is running low, a larger chunk of data is read from the file object. So the first `reader()` pulled in data into abuffer, and then when the second `csv.reader()` starts reading the file object has been forwarded to the next chunk. The same applies for the third reader you create.

Loop over `reader`, not `csv.reader(fin)`:

```
reader=csv.reader(fin)
next(reader, None)
for row in reader:
    # ...
    for row in reader:
```

I'm not quite sure why you are using two loops here however. If you wanted to split out writing data to separate files based on a date, store your open files in a dictionary, that you can then select an outgoing file from.

You also want to use a `csv.writer()` object for writing out rows to a new file, rather than use manual concatenation with commas:

```
try:
    open_writing_files = {}
    writers = {}

    for f in file_list:
        with open (f, 'rb') as fin:
            reader = csv.reader(fin)
            next(reader, None)

            for row in reader(fin):
                if row[1] not in ('abc', 'xyz'):
                    # not interesting, continue to the next row
                    continue

                file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[5], '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
                writer = writers.get(file_date)
                if writer is None:
                    # no writer for this date yet, create one
                    text_file = open("Report_for_{}.txt".format(file_date), "wb")
                    open_writing_files[file_date] = text_file
                    writer = writers[file_date] = csv.writer(text_file)
                    writer.writerow(['<field0>', '<date>', '<field2>', '<field3>'])

                # construct a new row for the output file, consisting of
                # indices 0, the date, indices 2, 3, 4 and 1.
                writer.writerow([row[0], file_date] + row[2:5] + [row[1]])

finally:
    for fileobj in open_writing_files.itervalues():
        fileobj.close()
```

The above:

1. opens files for a given date just once per program.
2. uses `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` for each file just once.
3. uses best practices for CSV file reading and writing by opening the files in binary mode. The `csv` module handles newline processing correctly that way.
4. ensures that all writing files are closed only when all CSV reading has completed.
5. tests for interesting rows early; that way you won't open extra per-date output files for dates that only appear in rows you skip.

Comment: @martijin_pieters

Comment: thanks @martijn-pieters. This code is much more elegant and refined than my attempt.
I have few issue here. I guess I must be doing something wrong but could not figure out what.
i am using 'if row[1] in ('abc', 'xyz'):' 
it filters just the top 1 record (with filter) but does not loop through the file. what am i doing wrong here.
other changes that I made are :
replaced 'for row in reader(fin):' with 'for row in reader:'

Comment: @user3017186: hrm, it seems I dropped an important line of code there; I added `continue` back in. This skips *just that one row*, not all of the file.

Comment: @martijin_pieters thanks again. works like charm with the modification.
another question - is there a reason why you took negative list 
'for row[] not in (.....)'
as against the usual shortlist of filtering if something satisfies a condition. 
Is there a programmatic advantage or is it personal/individual preference ?

Comment: @user3017186: if you invert the test and drop the `continue`, you have to indent the rest of the loop body. It is simply just to skip this iteration, avoiding over-indentation.